# Highest performance way to route traffic from IPv4 to IPv6 on Linux?

Tags: iptables, routing, port-forwarding, ipv6, ipv4

I have a use case where I want to forward certain IPv4 ports incoming into a machine, to to the same ports on another machine that uses IPv6.

I assume I can do this with [auto]ssh, but wonder if this is high performance, or if there is something else I could use? IPtables is one option, but I understand that this is IPv4 only and that I therefore need to use IP6tables. Will that work for IPv4 <-> IPv6 (bidirectional)?

What are my options for the highest performance, and preferably something that can run as a service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `socat`. It's a relay for bidirectional data transfers between two independent data channels. You can forward ipv4 to ipv6 and the other way around too.

Example for port 4000:

```
sudo socat TCP4-LISTEN:4000,fork TCP6:[xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx]:4000
```

Comment: yeah. I've done exactly that. Here's what I did:
`sudo socat TCP4-LISTEN:4000,fork TCP6:[xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx]:4000`
if you want to add that line to your answer I'll accept it. That line btw forwards port 4000 on IPv4 to port 4000 on the IPv6 address (the xxxx need to be changed obviously to your target IP address).

Comment: @ThomasBrowne done, and I'm glad it's working for you